# The Player's Appearence

Tags: hello-neighbor

We haven't seen what the player in the game Hello Neighbor looked like. There is no third person mode in the game in any version (Pre-Alpha, Alpha 1, Alpha 2, Alpha 3). Is there any way to find out the player's third person appearance?

Comment: maybe in the gamefiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that by using the debug console, you can view your player **ONLY** in Alpha 2 and 3, due to the fact that the Player didn't have arms in Pre-Alpha or Alpha 1. Also, in the beginning cutscene of Alpha 3, The Player can be seen driving the car to park next to his house across from his neighbor's.

Answer (score 3):

There have been people who have gotten underneath the map. Under there you find the basement (unplayable under most circumstances) and a model that, considering the placement and such, is meant to be the player. [source](http://helloneighbor.gamepedia.com/The_Player)

Comment: Jacksepticeye has a video where he does that, you can see the player model in all it's glory